# Sticky Footer on a Site with 100% height

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer

I'm trying to get a sticky footer on a page with 100% heigth in every tag. 
My problem is that, if the content is bigger than the display and I scroll downwards, the footer is no longer at the bottom of the page. 
The footer stays at the position like this: [Picture of the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xunz.png)

Here is an example:(Sorry that was the wrong link..)
http://jsfiddle.net/qt3m1p4c/

```
<html style:"height: 100%">
   <body style:"height: 100%">
        A lot of Content
   </body>
   <footer style:"position: absolute; bottom: 0;"> 
        Sticky Footer 
   </footer>
</html>
```

Does someone no how to fix this, without removing the heigth attributes?

Comment: The position: fixed for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set position: fixed to your footer, this means whatever happens on your page, this element will stand in same place, [here your code with changed position](http://jsfiddle.net/apk0zaj5/1/)

```
 .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: @MarcoGöpfrich yes, to solve that, specify some height to your footer, and add padding equals to this value to your wrapper:)

Answer (score 0):

Put the footer INSIDE the content wrapper and change the CSS as follows:

```
.pageContentWrapper {
    padding-bottom:100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    [...]
}
```

Here's a fiddle: (EDITED, I forgot to add `box-sizing: border-box;` at first): http://jsfiddle.net/uc6y5dhs/1/